# Value not changed by @Override Method

Tags: java, android, annotations, overriding

I want to check if a user is logged in in the app, for this I have the method `loggedIn()`:

```
private Boolean loggedIn = false;

public boolean loggedIn() {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("ID", "me");
    Buddy.get("users/me", parameters, new BuddyCallback<User>(User.class) {
        @Override
        public void completed(BuddyResult<User> result) {
            if (result.getIsSuccess()) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
            }
        }
    });
    return loggedIn;
}

public void setLoggedIn(Boolean loggedIn){
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
}
```

So when the user is logged in, it executes the `setLoggedIn(true);` line, this works.

The only problem is that this the method `loggedIn()` always returns `false`, whether `setLoggedIn(true);`is executed or not. Does this has something to do with the `@Override` annotation?

Comment: Ummm... there's a call back there, I'm thinking `setLoggedIn(true);` hasn't happened by the time you `return loggedIn`.

Comment: So what can I do the be sure that `setLoggedIn(true);` happened before I `return loggedIn`?  Something like `Thread.sleep();` wouldn't work here I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `loggedIn()`, you are performing a potentially asynchronous call to `Buddy.get`. This means that `Buddy.get` is likely spawning a new thread, on which `completed` is called.

The safe way to handle this is to change `boolean loggedIn()` to `void loggedIn()`. You would then give whatever class all this is in some kind of property change listener, for example:

```
public interface OnLoggedInChangedListener {
    public void onLoggedInChange(boolean loggedIn);
}

private OnLoggedInChangedListener loggedInListener; // This could also be a list of weak references

public void setOnLoggedInChangedListener(OnLoggedInChangedListener l) {
    loggedInListener = l;
}

public void setLoggedIn(Boolean loggedIn){
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    if (loggedInListener != null) {
        loggedInListener.onLoggedInChange(loggedIn);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a more general property change listener, and associate different properties of your class with a property enum. ie, `OnLoggedInChangedListener` would become something like `PropertyChangeListener<MyClassPropertyEnum>` and `enum MyClassPropertyEnum { LOGGED_IN }`

Another option would be `loggedIn()` could accept a listener as an argument, which you could call after you call `setLoggedIn()`